# How to insert a datatable to an access database in C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have 2 `table` in an access `database`

now I want to select from one `table` and insert them into another one.

this is my code but it shows an exception in line `Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

> {"Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'System.Object[]'."}

the code is :

```
public static void SetSelectedFeedIntoDB(Form2 frm2)
{
    string StrCon = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FeedLibraryConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    OleDbConnection Connection = new OleDbConnection(StrCon);
    OleDbDataAdapter DataA = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from FeedLibrary where ID=" + frm2.FeedSelectListBox.SelectedValue, Connection);
    DataTable DTable = new DataTable();
    DataA.Fill(DTable);

    OleDbCommand Cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    Cmd.Connection = Connection;

    Connection.Open();

    foreach (DataRow DR in DTable.Rows)
    {
        Cmd.CommandText = "insert into SelectedFeeds Values(" + DR.ItemArray + ")";
        Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    Connection.Close();
}
```

what should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your error is caused by the fact that you are concatenating the ItemArray property of a DataRow to a string. In this case the ItemArray (that is an instance of an object[]) has no method that automatically produces a string from its values and thus returns the class name as a string "object[]" but of course this produces the meaningless sql string

```
"insert into SelectedFeeds Values(object[])";
```

But you could simply build a [SELECT .... INTO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208934(v=office.12).aspx) statement that will do everything for you without using DataTables and Adapters

```
string cmdText = @"SELECT FeedLibrary.* INTO [SelectedFeeds] 
                   FROM FeedLibrary
                   where ID=@id";
using(OleDbConnection Connection = new OleDbConnection(StrCon))
using(OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdText, Connection))    
{
     Connection.Open();
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32( frm2.FeedSelectListBox.SelectedValue);
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

However, the `SELECT ... INTO` statement creates the target table but gives error if the target table already exists. To solve this problem we need to discover if the  target exists. If it doesn't exist we use the first `SELECT ... INTO` query, otherwise we use a [INSERT INTO ..... SELECT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208861(v=office.12).aspx)

```
 // First query, this creates the target SelectedFeeds but fail if it exists
 string createText = @"SELECT FeedLibrary.* INTO [SelectedFeeds] 
                       FROM FeedLibrary
                       where ID=@id";
 // Second query, it appends to SelectedFeeds but it should exists
 string appendText = @"INSERT INTO SelectedFeeds
                       SELECT * FROM FeedLibrary
                       WHERE FeedLibrary.ID=@id";

using(OleDbConnection Connection = new OleDbConnection(StrCon))
using(OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("", Connection))    
{
     Connection.Open();

     // Get info about the SelectedFeeds table....
     var schema = Connection.GetSchema("Tables", 
                   new string[] { null, null, "SelectedFeeds", null});

     // Choose which command to execute....
     cmd.CommandText = schema.Rows.Count > 0 ? appendText : createText;

     // Parameter @id is the same for both queries
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32( frm2.FeedSelectListBox.SelectedValue);

     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Here we have two different queries, the first one create the `SelectedFeeds` table as before, the second one appends into that table.
To discover if the target table has already been created I call [Connection.GetSchema](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135983(v=vs.110).aspx) to retrieve a datatable (schema) where there is a row if the table `SelectedFeeds` exists or no row if there is no such table.
At this point I set the OleDbCommand with the correct statement to execute.

Comment: thanks, I select from FeedLibrary with specific ID, what about that ?

Comment: All right added the WHERE part  missing and using a parameter instead of string concatenation (of course I assume that the ID field is an Integer type on the database)

Comment: tnx again I tried your cod, for the first time it worked (it crated the table) but after that the feed don't add to this table and exception is :  {"Table 'SelectedFeeds' already exists."}

Comment: If the table already exists then the query should be changed to INSERT INTO .... SELECT

Comment: Sorry for bothering you, using your edited code gives this exception {"Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '* FeedLibrary\r\n                       where FeedLibrary.ID=@i'."}